# How to the use same camera for two different applications?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using my webcam using opencv in python in Windows 10. My purpose is to use webcam even if it is used by another app without getting any error.

Kindly tell me if it is possible. And if yes, please describe how to perform this task.

Comment: Windows can't do that. there are ways to create virtual video devices and replicate the real video source's feed into those. I don't know about those methods. [there appear to be programs that do this conveniently](https://superuser.com/questions/741429/running-webcam-with-multiple-applications).

Comment: In GStreamer you can add T connections (splitter) and app-sinks to feed a camera to an application.